# Ruby: adding a hash to a master hash returns nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, hash

I'm writing a small CSV parser in Ruby. The CSV parser works fine, but I can't add my `row` to `hash`. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the parser:

```
require 'smarter_csv'

f = File.open('installs.csv')
hash = {}

csv = SmarterCSV.process(f, strip_chars_from_headers: /"|:/)
csv.each do |row|
  coords = row[:location_1].lines.to_a[1..-1].join
  row[:address] = coords
  hash << row
end

p hash
```

This returns a `undefined method '<<' for {}:Hash (NoMethodError)` error. What's going on?

Comment: What you call `hash` should be an array instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [merge!](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge!) to insert Hash into another Hash, It behaves like `Array <<`

```
a = {'1' => 2}
b = {'2' => 3}
c = {}
c.merge!(a) # c = {'1' => 2}
c.merge!(b) # c = {'1' => 2, '2' => 3}
```

If you want an `Array` of `Hashes`, why do you don't use `Array` object instead of Hash

```
require 'smarter_csv'

f = File.open('installs.csv')
a = []

csv = SmarterCSV.process(f, strip_chars_from_headers: /"|:/)
csv.each do |row|
  coords = row[:location_1].lines.to_a[1..-1].join
  row[:address] = coords
  a << row
end

p a # will result in array of rows, each row is hash
```

Comment: This is good but what if I'm iterating each merge? Only the last `row` then exists in the `hash`.

Answer (score 1):

For Hash use merge or merge! with ! to persist the change to the object.

```
hash_one = {a: 1, b: 3, c: 2}
=> {a: 1, b: 3, c: 2}
hash_two = {d: 89, e: 34, f: 1}
=> {d: 89, e: 34, f: 1}
hash_two.merge!(hash_one)
=> {a: 1, b: 3, c: 2, d: 89, e: 34, f: 1}
```

Use << for Array object.